# Selenium to click on corresponding description title

Tags: c#, selenium

I am developing a selenium application using c# language.

I have some data like this in my web page.

```
Description     Appname      Price       Validity
 some desc1      app1         20           7
 some desc2      app2         150          50
 some desc3      app3         65           20
```

All the titles starting with "some desc","app" has got some hyper link on that. I can make selenium find the appname by making use of PartialLinkText. What I want is to make selenium move left of the finding app and click on the description of that particular app.

For example, if I am searching for app2 it should click on some desc2 correctly.

Is this possible??

Your valuable comments are really appreciated..

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have not extensively used it myself but I believe clickAt(locator,coordinates) will help you achieve this. You will have to experiment with the offset though.You can find a similar approach [here](http://seleniumready.blogspot.gr/2010/09/how-to-use-selenium-clickat-command.html).